# New Discord Slash Commands

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Recently, discord added support for slash commands for your own application. I read through the documentation for it, and I've tried to search for some videos (however the feature did JUST come out) but I do not understand what I actually have to do to get it working. I am using WebStorm (js, node.js). Has anyone successfully made a slash command, and if so, how?

[Documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the regular `discord.js`, by now its `v12.5.1`.

This is just a sample, but worked for me.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    client.api.applications(client.user.id).guilds(YOUR_GUILD_ID_HERE).commands.post({
        data: {
            name: "hello",
            description: "hello world command"
            // possible options here e.g. options: [{...}]
        }
    });


    client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async interaction => {
        const command = interaction.data.name.toLowerCase();
        const args = interaction.data.options;

        if (command === 'hello'){ 
            // here you could do anything. in this sample
            // i reply with an api interaction
            client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
                data: {
                    type: 4,
                    data: {
                        content: "hello world!!!"
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });
});

client.login(token);
```

Of course you can have options, see documentation...

IDE won't register the new code...at least my php storm currently does'nt :)

However, its important to give the bot the correct permissions to use this type of command!

So go to [Discord.com/developers](https://discord.com/developers/applications), select your application, go to `OAuth2` and select

> application.commands

from the scope section. This should be at the bottom of the middle column. You should select `bot` as well and under `Bot Permissions`you set some other specific permissions. Then use that new invite link to reinvite the bot.

Without `application.commands` permission, the command won't work and you will receive some error like `Missing Access` or some similar.

**IMPORTANT THINGS**

1. Use `.guilds('11231...').comma` to test these commands. When not using this, it takes round about 1h to get active. Using it will activate it immediately.
2. Give the bot the correct permission. `application.commands`

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the detailed response, how do I give the application.commands permission. I'm not able to find it anywhere in the developer hub!?

Edit: Found it! Its in the OAuth section in the developer hub

Comment: shoudln't `.guilds('11231...').comma` be `.guilds('11231...').commands.get()`

Comment: not when you want to post something. of  course you got different methods to do what ever you want, depending on what you want ^^

Comment: Does this code have to run every time the bot starts? and do the slash commands appear in Discord if the bot is down?

Comment: @ma1234 commands are kind of preloaded in discord bot. as you can see, part of the command is in ready section, what actually indicates that the bot is running. command will also disapear if bot is not online.. or at least be unusable and disapear if bot is of for a longer time i guess.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I don't usually work with discord.js but I was able to find some good documentation on this. You should be able to do it like this with "client" defined.

```
const interactions = require("discord-slash-commands-client");

const client = new interactions.Client(
  "you unique bot token",
  "your bots user id"
);
```

If the client is defined as shown, then a /command should work if defined like this.

```
// will create a new command and log its data. 
//If a command with this name already exist will that be overwritten.
client.createCommand({
    name: "your command name",
    description: "description for this command",
  })
  .catch(console.error)
  .then(console.log);
```

Comment: Hello, Unfortunately, My IDE tells me that the required discord slash commands module is not found. Secondly, instead of client, I use bot, and I use the variable bot in other locations so my IDE also tells me that it's already defined :/ Do you have a solution to this?

Comment: You have to add the module to your IDE. If you use Visual Studio Code type `npm i discord-slash-commands-client` into your terminal. And if you use `bot` instead of `client`, simply rename `client` from @Shifu's code into `bot`. @Shreyas007

Comment: more specifically, you have to add the module to your node project.