# Use Slash Commands in all servers where have a bot without GuildID (Discord.js v12)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want people to be able to use Slash Commands against my bot on **any** server, as long as the bot is there. I have further granted the bot `application.commands` permission. I was referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65422307/16410937), but it seems to require the server's GuildID. Can I allow anyone using Slash Commands to come to my bot without a GuildID? And how do people use it? (I use Commands Handler)

*sorry for my bad english*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use a [**global slash command**](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#registering-a-command). Global meaning that it works across all guilds the bot is in and you don't need to provide any guild id.

```js
client.on("ready", () => {

    // Register global slash command
    client.api.applications(client.user.id).commands.post({
        data: {
            name: "hello",
            description: "Say 'Hello, World!'"
        }
    });

    // Listen for an interaction (e.g. user typed command)
    client.ws.on("INTERACTION_CREATE", (interaction) => {
        // Access command properties
        const commandId = interaction.data.id;
        const commandName = interaction.data.name;
        
        // Reply only to commands with name 'hello'
        if (commandName == "hello") {
            // Reply to an interaction
            client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
                data: {
                    type: 4,
                    data: {
                        content: "Hello, World!"
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

This is how would a user use your command:

[image]

And the reply looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the link should be changed to this one now: https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#registering-a-command

Comment: @UsmanSabuwala I have made an edit then, thanks.